# Bootstrap HTML5 navbar-brand and form

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have problem for bootstrap. In navbar-brand.

I want to create this:

[image: I want to create it]

and I have this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/papai.pl.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- HTML5 shim and Respond.js for IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
    <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
  </head>
  <body>
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
<div class="container">
<button type="button" class="navbar-toggle"
data-toggle="collapse"
data-target=".navbar-collapse">
<span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
<span class="icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="icon-bar"></span> 
<span class="icon-bar"></span> 
</button>
<div class="navbar-brand"><input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputHorizontalSuccess" placeholder="Photos, people or groups"></div>
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right line-inline">
<button type="button" class="btn btn-link" id="signin-btn">Sign In</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="signin-btn">Sign In</button>
</ul>

</div>
</div>
</nav>
    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I searched the internet half without result, there is always a problem with form search.

Comment: Your question is very unclear. Please edit for clarity. Thanks.

Comment: agree with @Difster

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, so just to clarify, it seems like you want to create a navbar like the one you linked on your own site, so you copied the HTML of that site into yours. However, HTML is not enough, you'll also need CSS and Javascript to be able to make it look the same.

While you could copy over all the CSS and JS files, you'll end up with a lot of redundant code, and you won't know how it works. I recommend that you keep the HTML, and try to write the rest yourself. It will be hard, but you'll learn a lot.